# How to use PubNub in an Android app?

Tags: android, pubnub

I am trying to develop an Android app for social media sharing. I know how PubNub uses cloud servers to share data with lightening fast speed and a security. I want to use it in my app.
If there is an API, let me know how it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the [PubNub Android SDK on github](https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android)
And the [official PubNub Android docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-java-sdk)

Most of the details for how to use it properly are right there on the README. There's even sample apps for you to browse through if you need further details.

Comment: I am confused a little. I need "History" to receive live messages when it sent?!?!?!

Comment: @David - are you still in need of assistance using history? History is not realtime, rather, it is use to retrieve missed messages while the user was offline and unable to receive the messages in realtime as a subscriber. Let me know if you have additional questions - probably a separate thread than this post, though.

Comment: thank you I found the solution with contact to pubnub support team email.

Comment: @justin hyper link not working (PubNub Android SDK on github) please update